# Вырезать из текста тег img с содержанием data:image/svg+xml

Tags: php, str-replace

Здравствуйте. Есть переменная `$text` в которой имеется текст.
В тексте встречаются теги  которые содержат:

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/svg&quot; width=&quot;960&quot; height=&quot;640&quot;%3E%3C/svg%3E" />
```

Каким образом вырезать этот тег, если его **src** начинается с **data:image/svg+xml** ?

P.S. вырезать просто все теги **img** - не вариант, так как нужно вырезать только те, которые содержат svg.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: preg_replace() вам тут нужен, а не str_replace().

Comment: @Visman , а регулярное выражение как будет выглядеть для моих целей?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так

```
$text = preg_replace('%<img [^>]*?src=["\']data:image/svg\+xml[^>]+>%', '', $text);
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/ovg0Yy/3